# kill command working despite error

Tags: macos, mac, unix, terminal, kill

after running this command `kill -9 <PID> for ./sc_serv`. I am getting this output below:

```
-bash: kill: for: arguments must be process or job IDs
-bash: kill: ./sc_serv: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

If I run `ps` I can see the PID has been terminated or at-least is no longer listed. Killing the process is all I really need to do at this point but Im worried about the meaning of the output and would like to know what it means before I move on with my project...

I am still learning so if there is any other relevant info or explanations they would be greatly appreciated of course.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `for ./sc_serv` supposed to mean?

Comment: That is just the specific executable file I am running. Its a shoutcast server.

Comment: But what does it mean to `kill`???  To `kill` it's just two more processes to kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `killall $processname` to terminate a process by name or `kill $pid` to terminate a process by PID.

`kill -9 $pid for ./sc_serv` terminated the process by PID but showed an error about the `for ./sc_serv` arguments:

```
arguments must be process or job IDs
```